# Viewbadger Count not getting updated dynamically

Tags: android, badge, activity-lifecycle

when database gets updated with any action , the viewbadger counter is not getting updated on DashboardActivity.

```
public static BadgeView badge1;
public static BadgeView badge2;


@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

      Badgeupdate(); // function to update badge           
}


public void Badgeupdate() {   

    neworders_count=0;     
    pendingorders_count=0;        


    badge1 = new BadgeView(this, v1); // v11 is View
    fetch_neworders_count();  // fetch data count query
    CurrentActivity.badge1.setText(neworders_count + "");
    badge1.show();

    badge2 = new BadgeView(this, v2); // v2 is View
    fetch_pendingorders_count();  // fetch data count query
    CurrentActivity.badge2.setText(pendingorders_count + "");
    badge2.show();  



}
```

I have user Viewbadger library - https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-viewbadger

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please Try below code:

```
public static BadgeView badge1;
  badge1 = new BadgeView(MainActivity.this, v1); //v1 is view selected to set badge

            badge1.setText("0");
            badge1.show();

MainActivity.badge1.setText("hello badge"); //call it from anywhere to update
```

In your badge update only use badge.setText("hello"); not any more thing, you're here creating them again and again.

Comment: No. Once i click on it (opens another activity & perform changes in data) and come back to this. Its not getting updated

Comment: @Androider hey , have you figured out how to change the value of viewbadger dynamically.